# Error when trying to get a single record form SQLite (Ionic/Angularjs/SQLite)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sqlite, ionic-framework

I am trying to display a single record from an SQLite. But got an error from console:

"Error: Failed to execute 'item' on 'SQLResultSetRowList': The index provided (0) is greater than or equal to the maximum bound (0).
at Error (native)
at Object.self.getById"

The caller

```js
$scope.DisplayMember = function(RegId) {
      Team.get(RegId).then(function(data){  $scope.Singledata= data;});
    };
```

Called this:

```js
self.get = function(memberId) {
      var parameters = [memberId];
      return DBA.query("SELECT id, name FROM team WHERE id = (?)", parameters)
        .then(function(result) {
          return DBA.getById(result);
        });
    }
```

And lastly this:

```js
// Proces a single result
    self.getById = function(result) {
      var output = null;
      output = angular.copy(result.rows.item(0));
      return output;
    }
```

Thanks for your kind help
Here is the controller and services file:

```js
var db = null;

angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ngCordova'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform, $cordovaSQLite) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }


    if(window.cordova) {
      // App syntax
      db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB("myapp.db");
    } else {
      // Ionic serve syntax
      db = window.openDatabase("myapp.db", "1.0", "My app", -1);
    }

    $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS team (id integer primary key, name text)");
  });
})

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
    $stateProvider
      .state('list',{
        url: '/list',
        templateUrl: 'templates/list.html'

      })
    .state('edit',{
      url: '/edit/:RegId',
      templateUrl: 'templates/edit.html'


      });
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/list');


  })

  .controller('TeamCtrl', function($scope, Team, $state) {
          $scope.team = [];
          $scope.team = null;
          $scope.RegId = $state.params.RegId;
          $scope.updateTeam = function() {
            Team.all().then(function(team){
              $scope.team = team;
            });
          }

          $scope.updateTeam();

          $scope.createNewTeamMember = function(member) {
            console.log("hello");
            Team.add(member);
            $scope.updateTeam();
          };

          $scope.removeMember = function(member) {
            Team.remove(member);
            $scope.updateTeam();
          };

          $scope.editMember = function(origMember, editMember) {
            Team.update(origMember, editMember);
            $scope.updateTeam();
          };

          $scope.DisplayMember = function(member) {
          Team.all(member).then(function(data){  $scope.Ourdata= data;console.log($scope.Ourdata);});
          };

          $scope.DisplaySingleMember = function(RegId) {
            Team.get(RegId).then(function(data){ $scope.task= data;console.log($scope.task);});
          };


  })


  .factory('DBA', function($cordovaSQLite, $q, $ionicPlatform) {
    var self = this;

    // Handle query's and potential errors
    self.query = function (query, parameters) {
      parameters = parameters || [];
      var q = $q.defer();

      $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
        $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, parameters)
          .then(function (result) {
            q.resolve(result);
          }, function (error) {
            console.warn('I found an error');
            console.warn(error);
            q.reject(error);
          });
      });
      return q.promise;
    }

    // Proces a result set
    self.getAll = function(result) {
      var output = [];

      for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
        output.push(result.rows.item(i));
      }
      return output;
    }

    // Proces a single result
    self.getById = function(result) {
      var output = null;
      output = angular.copy(result.rows.item(0));
      return output;
    }

    return self;
  })

  .factory('Team', function($cordovaSQLite, DBA) {
    var self = this;

    self.all = function() {
      return DBA.query("SELECT id, name FROM team")
        .then(function(result){
          return DBA.getAll(result);
        });
    }

    self.get = function(memberId) {
      var parameters = [memberId];
      return DBA.query("SELECT id, name FROM team WHERE id = (?)", parameters)
        .then(function(result) {
          return DBA.getById(result);
        });
    }

    self.add = function(member) {
      var parameters = [member.id, member.name];
      return DBA.query("INSERT INTO team (id, name) VALUES (?,?)", parameters);
    }

    self.remove = function(member) {
      var parameters = [member.id];
      return DBA.query("DELETE FROM team WHERE id = (?)", parameters);
    }

    self.update = function(origMember, editMember) {
      var parameters = [editMember.id, editMember.name, origMember.id];
      return DBA.query("UPDATE team SET id = (?), name = (?) WHERE id = (?)", parameters);
    }

    return self;
  })
```

Comment: What is the plugin are you using?

Comment: Cordova SQLite storage... It's working now sir. But i have another problem with two-way data binding. I am binding a display page to an edit page with the hope of populating it with data from display page to edit. But nothing shows up on the edit page sir.

Comment: is this https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage?

Comment: Could you please post all the code of controller and service you are using?

Comment: Ok sir, Here is the link to the whole code. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzqArLT5flPEZ19SUEptWmtFZzA/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Posted here above also sir. Many thanks for your concerns.